# Black Scholes to Heat Equation - Substitution

Tags: black-scholes

Sorry as really basic question. Chapter 8 of Wilmott introduces Q Finance the BS equation is transformed into the heat equation. Firstly by using
$
V(S,t) \rightarrow \mathrm{e}^{-r(T - t)}U(S,t) 
$
and then $ \tau = T - t $

Resulting in:
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau} = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial \xi^2} + (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi} 
$$

The final change of variables used is $ x  = \xi + (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau $ which results in the heat equation in terms of $ x $ and $ \tau $.

Could someone please tell me how exactly this variable change reduces the above equation to the heat equation? I seem to be getting $ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2} = 0 $. After applying the chain rule for each of the terms.

Comment: You are missing one change of variable at least. You need to take the log of S to make the equation with constant coefficients

Comment: Sorry I should have said $ \xi = log(S) $ so that part has been done. It's just the last step.

Comment: This is just chain rule

Comment: Yeah think I've not had enough sleep haha. But wouldn't $ \frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau} =  \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}   =  (r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}) \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$ ?? Which then gives the second derivative of x as being equal to zero?

Comment: you mixed yourself up. Just write it as a new function $V(\tau,x):=U(\tau,x-(...)\tau)$ and take the $\tau$ derivative on both sides to get the heat equation for $V$

Answer (score 3):

The starting formulation of the Black-Scholes equation as found in the OP question:

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \xi^2} + \left(r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \frac{\partial U}{\partial \xi}
$$

This will be proven to be equivalent to the heat equation (the parabolic PDE) after a change of coordinates $(\xi, \tau) \rightarrow (x, \tau)$ defined as:

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \xi + \left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \tau\\
\tau &= \tau
\end{align}
$$

Use of the chain rule clarifies how first derivatives change when passing from a set of coordinates to the other:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi (x, \tau)} (*) &= \overbrace{\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi}}^{= 1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (*) + \overbrace{\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial \xi}}^{= 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} (*)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau (x, \tau)} (*) &= \underbrace{\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}}_{= r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (*) + \underbrace{\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial \tau}}_{= 1} \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} (*)
\end{align}
$$

The second order derivative $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2 (x, \tau)}$ needs also to be evaluated. Seen from above that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi (x, \tau)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, this is easily:

$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2 (x, \tau)} (*) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} (*) \right) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} (*)
$$

Applying the above reformulations of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi (x, \tau)}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau (x, \tau)}$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2 (x, \tau)}$ to the Black-Scholes equation eliminates the first order derivative term and yields the classic heat equation:

$$
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}\cancel{\left( r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau} &= \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2} + \cancel{\left(r - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}} \qquad \qquad \Longrightarrow\\
\Longrightarrow \qquad \qquad \frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau} &= \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why in the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau(x,\tau)}(*)$ we have $\tau$ as a function of $x$ and $\tau$ instead of $x$ and $\xi$, i.e.: $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau(x,\xi)}$?

Comment: @userPrimeNumber What is of interest here is the change of coordinates $(\xi, \tau) \rightarrow (x, \tau)$, so $\tau$ has to be expressed in the plane $(x, \tau)$. $x$ is the new coordinate with the same meaning of $\xi$: the plane $(x, \xi)$ in this context is meaningless.